# Determining distance between two distances given acceleration, max velocity, deceleration and total time.

Tags: calculus, physics

PROBLEM: A train accelerates from rest at one train station with $a= 0.72t$ $m/s^2$, until it reaches its maximum speed of $18 m/s$. Its deceleration heading into the next train station is $3.0 m/s^2$. If the journey between the two stations takes 6 minutes and 20 seconds, what is the distance between the stations?

WORKED ANSWER: I initially drew a $v-t$ graph, with maximum velocity of $18 m/s$ and maximum time of $380$ seconds. So the graph looks like a triangle with a peak of $18$. One edge of the triangle has a slope of $0.72t$ and the other edge has a slope of $-3$. So, the triangle is halved at time $t_1$ which I presumed is unknown.

PERSONAL QUESTION 1/2: According to the problem given, did I draw the graph correctly in order for me to answer the question?

WORKED ANSWER continued:

For $t \le t_1$ $v=0.36t^2$:

$18 = 0.36t_1^2$

$t_1=5\sqrt2$

$\therefore$  $\Delta x=A_1+A_2$

$=(1/2*5\sqrt2*18)+(1/2*18*(380-5\sqrt2))$
$=3420m$

PERSONAL QUESTION 2/2: If the graph I have drawn is correct, is my procedure correct and hence is my answer correct?

Comment: You have not shown the graph. Yes, $t_1=5\sqrt2$, and the graph is a parabola from $0\to5\sqrt2$, having the equation $v=0.36t^2$. This means the portion of the graph for $t\le t_1$ is not a straight line, and your $A_1$ term is erroneous. $$A_1=\int_0^{5\sqrt2}0.36t^2dt$$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri, so does $A_1+$$A_2=$$\Delta x$ still apply but I just made a mistake for $A_1$, but $A_2$ is correct?

Comment: I believe the $t$ in $a=0.72t$ is in minutes

Comment: Since the second part involves constant acceleration, your $A_2$ is correct.

Comment: @KM101 So is $A_1 = integral$ correct? Wondering since I'm unsure.

Comment: What you mean is displacement is the integral of velocity with respect to time, which is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graph for the first part isn’t correct. The integral of a linear function gives a parabola.

Just like how uniformly increasing velocity (constant acceleration) produces a parabolic $x-t$ (position-time) graph. For $a = 0.72t$, $j = 0.72$. $j$ represents “jerk” (rate of change of acceleration).

Hence, $$\Delta x = \frac{1}{6}jt^3+\frac{1}{2}a_0t^2+v_0t = \frac{1}{6}(0.72)\left(5\sqrt{2}\right)^3 = 30\sqrt{2}$$

(Since the object starts from rest, the terms involving $a_0$ and $v_0$ become $0$.) The formula above can be derived via repeated integration.

You can also use integration, which is also viable:

$$v(t) = \int a(t)dt = \int 0.72t = \frac{1}{2}0.72t^2 = 0.36t^2$$

You have $t_0 = 0$ and $t_1 = 5\sqrt{2}$, so

$$\Delta x = \int_{0}^{5\sqrt{2}}0.36t^2 = \frac{1}{3}(0.36)\left(5\sqrt{2}\right)^3 = 30\sqrt{2}$$

The rest of your answer is correct because there is constant acceleration, producing a triangular $v-t$ graph.

Comment: The acceleration is $0.72t$, not $0.72$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I’ve edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Is this $\Delta x$ for $A_1$?

Comment: Yes, your $A_2$ is correct.

Comment: Also, sorry for the repetitive editing, I didn’t initially read the question correctly.